# React Material UI Grid footer change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

have a problem with customising of footer in react material-ui grid.
As shown in the image (below).

**How do modify the**: `1 row selected`?

[image: img]

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [github code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/6a9c14554dfdfcc99805da80a853460390a0c32f/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/constants/localeTextConstants.ts#L55) and [localization docs](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/localization/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all for feedback.

See my solution based on the tip from @c0m1t!

```js
//setState on select onChange
const selectedRow = async (newSelection) => {
     let id = newSelection.rowIds[0];
     await dispatch({ type: FAT_SELECT_EDIT, payload:rows.filter(i => i.id === +id)[0] });
    };
     <DataGrid
             onSelectionChange={selectedRow}
             localeText={{
               footerRowSelected: (count) => `ID Selecionado: ${selected.id}`
                  }}
      />
```

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igx77.png

Answer (score 0):

Go the the inspect element-

1- Find the class that is applying the specific element

2- Try to modify the element, and get desired results and then copy the style

3- Go back to your project and override the style..

If you are still looking how to customize the MU classes, then visit their website.
Thanks